# Adding segments to jQuery.knob with image mask

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I'm using [JQueryKnob](https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob) and trying to add segments to the radial. I'm not well versed in Canvas drawing, so that didn't seem like the best road to take - what I really need to do is just overlay a mask image on the drawn Knob canvas element. I've tried variations of this and it doesn't seem to work (I'm guessing the mask can't apply to canvases?)

I started to dabble with trying to just draw alpha'd lines in the JQueryKnob draw method, but didn't really have any luck with that either.

Any ideas? I'm pretty lost here

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track...just draw your masked image inside the `draw` method of your knob.

[image]

```
$(".knob").knob({
    draw : function () {
        var ctx=this.g;
        var x=this.xy;
        var y=this.xy;
        var r=this.radius;
        var iw=img.width;
        var ih=img.height;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI*2);
        ctx.clip();
        ctx.drawImage( img,  0,0,iw,ih,  x-iw/2,y-ih/2,iw,ih );
        ctx.restore();
    }
});
```

**Here's example code and a Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/g8rx58hh/